# Unable to create a Docker image

Tags: python, docker

I would like to run my scrape.py in Docker on my Ubuntu. My steps:

1. I install docker using `sudo snap install docker`
2. I create a Docker file:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
CMD ["python", "scrape.py"]
```

2. In a folder I open my terminal and I try `docker image build /home/vojtam/Desktop/scrape_filer` . Both scrape.py and Dockerfile are in scrape_filer.
3. But I got an error

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

What is the problem, please? Thanks

Comment: Try `sudo docker image build`. Unless you added the docker to some specific groups, then you may need sudo to run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access Docker with a non-root user, you must simply execute this command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker your-user
```